# Wait for Cloud Firestore before rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a collection of computers and putting them into an array so I can render them using a map in my reactjs component return statement. However, the array is always empty. I'm guessing it has something to do with async / await but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code.

```
function Home()
{
    let computers = [];

    firestore.collection("computers").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            let data = doc.data();
            data.uid = data.id;
            computers.push(data);
        })
    })

    console.log(computers.length); // Always returns 0

    return (
        // Using computers.map to render every computer into its own component
    );

}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Yes, it's because of that. You will have to use useState to do this. Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1):

You really need to start from basics here and read up on [React Hooks](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). I will give you some code along with a Sandbox link to get you going.

The idea is to get your computers and then update your component's state with the aquired value, which will trigger a component re-redner with the state's value set to your computers array. Here is the idea:
(Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-river-p8f92?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const getComputers = () => { //This will sumulate your call to get computers.
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(['computer1', 'computer2']), 1000)
  })
}

function App() {
  const [computers, setComputers] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
      getComputers().then(computers => setComputers(computers))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Computers</h1>
      {computers.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```